# How much of a DNA difference is between Chicken of the Woods, and Hen of the Woods?

Tags: dna, mycology

I've noticed that when a COW is touching the ground it turns a gray color, but when on a log/tree it's bright orange. Is there a correlation between the DNA, and where it grows?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is changing color? The grass? The grass is going bright orange when you put a a tree log on it and grey when a cow step on it? Do you mean a change of color that takes a season to happen or is instantaneous? You ask `Is there a correlation between the DNA, and where it grows?` DNA of what? Are you talking about cows and trees, here? Is this question related to the claims about colors you made above? The title is talking about Chicken and hen but those are absent from your post!

Comment: Sorry, title is talking about "chicken of the woods" and "Hen of the woods" (not chicken and hen). And COW is a priori short hand for Chicken of the Woods. So, I suspect you talk about the color of the mushroom. Is your question "Are there genetic predisposition to growing low or high on a tree for a [chicken of the woods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laetiporus)?" or maybe "Are hen of the woods more likely to grow at low height on trees than chicken of the woods?"?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking essentially if the COW is just a hen growing on the side of a tree or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume from your comment that your question is

> Is a chicken of the woods just a hen of the woods growing on the side of a tree?

, which is very similar to me to

> Is a chicken of the woods and a hen of the woods the same species?

No, they are not the same species. Chicken of the woods is the common name of a number of species of the genus *[Laetiporus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laetiporus)*. Hen of the woods is the common name of the species *[Grifola frondosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grifola_frondosa)*. In fact, *Grifola* and *Laetiporus* don't even belong to the same family but only to the same order (order *[Polyporales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyporales)*).

According to the wikipedia links posted above, *Grifola frondosa* is indeed usually found at the base of the tree while *Laetiporus* is generally found in the wound of trees (mainly oak trees).